# Javascript battleship game hit detection not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write code to detect if a ship has been hit or not. I have 3 ships on the board and each takes up 3 cells. Using js I placed the 3 ships on the board. And when I run the fire method, only the last two ships show they've been hit, but the first ship at location 00,01,02 doesn't indicate that it's been hit, even once. Where did I go wrong?

```js
var view = {
  showMessage: function(msg) {
    var message = document.getElementById('message');
    message.innerHTML = msg;
  },

  showHit: function(location) {
    var cell = document.getElementById(location);
    cell.setAttribute('class', 'hit');
  },

  showMiss: function(location) {
    var cell = document.getElementById(location);
    cell.setAttribute('class', 'miss');
  }
}

var model = {
  boardSize: 7,
  numShips: 3,
  shipsSunk: 3,
  ships: [{
      location: [00, 01, 02],
      hits: ['', '', '']
    },
    {
      location: [10, 11, 12],
      hits: ['', '', '']
    },
    {
      location: [20, 21, 22],
      hits: ['', '', '']
    }
  ],

  fire: function(guess) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numShips; i++) {
      var ship = this.ships[i];
      var index = ship.location.indexOf(guess);
      if (index >= 0) {
        ship.hits[index] = 'hit';
        view.showHit(guess);
      }
    }
  }
};


model.fire(10);
model.fire(11);
model.fire(12);
model.fire(20);
model.fire(21);
model.fire(22);
/*
model.fire(00);
model.fire(01);
model.fire(02); */
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#message {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#board {
  background: url('board.jpg') no-repeat;
  width: 863px;
  height: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  left: 173px;
  top: 98px;
}

td {
  height: 94px;
  width: 94px;
}

form input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}

.hit {
  background: url('ship.png') no-repeat center center;
}

.miss {
  background: url('miss.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<div id='board'>
  <div id='message'></div>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id='00'></td>
      <td id='01'></td>
      <td id='02'></td>
      <td id='03'></td>
      <td id='04'></td>
      <td id='05'></td>
      <td id='06'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='10'></td>
      <td id='11'></td>
      <td id='12'></td>
      <td id='13'></td>
      <td id='14'></td>
      <td id='15'></td>
      <td id='16'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='20'></td>
      <td id='21'></td>
      <td id='22'></td>
      <td id='23'></td>
      <td id='24'></td>
      <td id='25'></td>
      <td id='26'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='30'></td>
      <td id='31'></td>
      <td id='32'></td>
      <td id='33'></td>
      <td id='34'></td>
      <td id='35'></td>
      <td id='36'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='40'></td>
      <td id='41'></td>
      <td id='42'></td>
      <td id='43'></td>
      <td id='44'></td>
      <td id='45'></td>
      <td id='46'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='50'></td>
      <td id='51'></td>
      <td id='52'></td>
      <td id='53'></td>
      <td id='54'></td>
      <td id='55'></td>
      <td id='56'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='60'></td>
      <td id='61'></td>
      <td id='62'></td>
      <td id='63'></td>
      <td id='64'></td>
      <td id='65'></td>
      <td id='66'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form action='#' method='get'>
    <input type='text' id='guessInput' placeholder='enter location: A0' />
    <input type='button' name='submit' value='Fire!' name='fire' />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `Fire` button has two names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coordinates 00, 01, and 02 are interpreted as `int`s and are therefore resolved to 0, 1, and 2, because it is assumed that the leading zero is not needed for an `int` value. You can fix this by using strings to represent and compare the coordinates. Instead of `model.fire(00)`, you will need `model.fire("00")`. Then to compare the input coordinates, you will need to compare `guess.charAt(0)` and `guess.charAt(1)` to determine if that coordinate is a hit.